# Как отделить извлеченный из pdf текст от символов которые в самом pdf отображаются как "изображения"

Tags: python, pdf

При попытке извлечь текст с помощью python (pymupdf) вместе с текстом я получаю символы, которые в самом pdf документе выглядят как изображения. Возможно это Лигатуры, но как это проверить

Как отделить текст не применяя OCR и регулярные выражения (и другие методы фильтрации)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Как отделить текст не применяя ...  другие методы фильтрации` отделять или не отделять?

Comment: Символы, которые в pdf отображаются в виде графики зачастую тоже выглядят как обычные буквы алфавита при извлечении или даже как фрагменты текста и просто отфильтровать и выкинуть не получится. 

Самое лучшее на данный момент решение, которое у меня работает это сортировка текста по шрифту и размеру и уже по разным признакам я выбираю только нужный мне шрифт и размер текста. Но это может не сработать для некоторых pdf документов, где шрифт и размер "графических" символов совпадает с обычным текстом

Comment: Да все правильно, нечего давать тестовые данные, пусть по фотографии гадают.

Comment: Ï
Ï
Ï
Ï
Ï
Ï
Ï
Ï
Ï
Ï
Ï
Ï
Ï
Ï
Î
Î Î
Î Î
Î
Î
mf
î
î
î
long
î î
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
ú ú
ú ú ú
j
j
j
j
j
j
{
{
{
{
}
}
a
}
}
Walking March

3
3
A

Comment: Текстовые данные абсолютно разные - это просто текст с разными символами, буквами алфавита на разных языках, словами и предложениями. Это мало чем поможет так как отсортировать как я сказал не получится.

Comment: А чем вас OCR не устраивает?

Comment: Мне важно получить максимально точный текст, а в моих pdf очень много разреженного текста (слова песни под нотами) с OCR не удается получить результат без ошибок - пробовал tesseract на разных режимах работы, но разреженный текст это слабое место для OCR. Пробовал также Детектировать текст, обучал свою модель на открытых данных и пробовал использовать готовые модели, но там часто модель путает набор нот с текстом( Для хорошего результата надо обучать на реальных данных, но делать столько разметки нет времени

Answer (score 0):

Лично я вижу такое решение: составить алфавит допустимых символов и пунктуации, а оставшееся просто опустить.

Алфавит такой:

```py
import string
ALPHABET = (" ".join(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation + string.printable) + "Ё Й Ц У К Е Н Г Ш Щ З Х Ъ Ф Ы В А П Р О Л Д Ж Э Я Ч С М И Т Ь Б Ю ё й ц у к е н г ш щ з х ъ ф ы в а п р о л д ж э я ч с м и т ь б ю").split()
```

Далее прогнать текст, который у Вас получился посимвольно и проверить есть ли каждый из этих символов в нашем алфавите.

Также если такая проверка не дает результатов и в полученном тексте есть бессвязный мусор из символов, то можно анализировать каждое слово на наличие таковых в языке, на котором написан PDF c помощью библиотеки `langdetect`:

```
from langdetect import detect
import string

def check_language(word):
    if word in (not (string.digits + string.punctuation + string.printable)):
        try:
            lang = detect(word)
            if lang == "ru": # Если документ написан на русском
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except:
            return False
```

Проверив таким образом каждое слово можно получить связный текст.

Решения топорные, но пока идей больше нет